# Running android app on the mobile phone and on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wrote an android application on `ICS` and set its minimum `SDK` to 8. I run the app on emulator and it worked correctly but when I install the .apk file on my mobile I got a force close. Why do I get this problem? The app is for OCR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/H1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/H2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/H3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I always get this notification in XML file:

```
[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image
```

Why?

Comment: connect your device with computer and see the logcat for error generated by device

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it is crashing, but the error you are getting is only a warning. The contentDescription is just for accessibility and not needed. The error that is causing the crash most likely exists elsewhere in your code.